# Дубликаты в HashSet

Tags: java

```
public class Car {

    String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car bugatti = new Car("Бугатти");
        Car ferrari = new Car("Феррари");
        Car audi = new Car("Ауди");
        Car ferrari2 = new Car("Феррари");
        Set<Car> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(bugatti);
        set.add(ferrari);
        set.add(audi);
        set.add(ferrari2);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Хотел спросить, вывожу в консоль данный код и выводит:

```
[Car{name='Феррари'}, Car{name='Ауди'}, Car{name='Феррари'}, Car{name='Бугатти'}]
```

Когда я в классе `Car` переопределяю `hashCode()` и `equals()` у меня выводится 1 феррари вот так:

```
[Car{name='Феррари'}, Car{name='Бугатти'}, Car{name='Ауди'}]
```

Ответьте по пунктам пожалуйста:
1. Для того чтобы "дубликация не работала" вы должны в своем классе переопределить `hashCode()` и `equals()` методы? (Ну как я вижу, да).
2. Правильно ли я всё сделал? Напишите свой пример для ясности
Заранее благодарю вас за помощь!

Comment: У вас `Car` - это класс. По умолчанию сравнение экземпляров классов идёт по ссылке (так что `ferrari == ferrari`, но `ferrari != ferrari2`). Если Вы хотите реализовать свою логику сравнения, то действительно необходимо переопределить `equals` и оптимальности ради `hashCode`

Comment: Хорошо описано в этой статье [Разбираемся с hashCode() и equals()](https://habr.com/ru/post/168195/)

Answer (score 0):

1. действительно Set не допускает дубликатов, сравнение объектов происходит через equals, поэтому с формальной точки зрения ваши классы Car не равны друг другу т.к. в реализации equals по умолчанию сравниваются ссылки
2. в собственных классах отображающих какую-либо предметную область (машину в вашем случае) переопределение equals и hashCode обязательно